# Show article modified date in Article Manager Administrator

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, article-manager

I'm trying to find a way to show the date an article was last modified in the article manager in Joomla 3.

Doing a google search I can only seem to find ways to do this so it's visible via the frontend of the website rather than in the administrator.

Answer (score 2):

If you look in 'Article manager':'Edit Article' -> 'Publishing' tab, do you see 'Modified Date' field?
What is your template in Administrator?

Comment: I'm using the default isis admin theme, I can't seem to find the Publishing tab in the article manager. I see a modified date in the publishing tab in the article but I wanted to know if there a way to show this in the article manager

Comment: As commented by @Lodder: _It won't show the modified date in the list of articles in the Article Manager_. But would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update: This is a core feature since J! 3.7.3 release.

We can now sort articles by Date Modified, using the Sorting Dropdown on the top-right side of the articles manager list.

[image: Sorting Articles by Date Modified in Admin]

[image: Sorted by Date Modified]

---

#### Initial answer

I worked on this feature for a customer and have submitted the code to be considered for inclusion with a future Joomla release.

The patch has now been merged and seems it is in the milestones for the next 3.7.3 version.

When it becomes available, it will be possible to select the Articles Sorting Order by Date Modified and the corresponding Date Column will turn to Date Modified.

If anyone is in hurry for this feature, he can go and get the patch from here:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/15825

---

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Goto backend -> Article manager -> Select and edit the existing article -> Publishing -> Here you can see the modified date in admin side.
```

If you want to see the article manager in frontend side

```
Goto backend -> Article manager -> Select and edit the existing article -> Options -> Here you can show or hide the modify date.
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you haven't found it yet, that's what you're loooking for:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=708&t=846690

Comment: Reading the link, it looks like it's a fix for Joomla 2.5, the tag in the question is for Joomla 3

Comment: The fix works totally fine for Joomla 3 as I used it for Joomla 3 myself.